# How to display updated multiple NStimer value in Tableview cell iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstimer

I want to set multiple running timer value in tableview so user easily checked how many time is remaining and stop any specific timer.

Multiple Timer Start and updated value display in `NSLog` perfectly.
User set `NSTimer` for particular recipe.
Now suppose user set timer for recipe1 in recipedetail and now back from that recipedetail.
Then again set timer for recipe2 in recipedetail and back from that recipedetail. 
and i want to All  timer value display in `UITableView`. And tableview placed on recipedetail screen.

So my point is TimerUpdated value display in `NSLog` but not display in tableview because every Recipedetails screen generate new object of `UITableView` So value is not updated perfactly

```
 -(IBAction)okBtn:(id)sender
    {
       [self countdownTimer];
    }
-(void)countdownTimer {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:recipeboxId forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"timer_%@",recipeboxId]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        // set timer

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
        (theAppDelegate).timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.6f
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
                                               userInfo:recipeboxId
                                                repeats:YES];
        [(theAppDelegate).timer fire];
    //    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];//Timer run in background

        [self CreateLocalNotification];
    }


    -(void)calculateTimeFromPicker
    {
        NSString *hoursStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[hoursArray objectAtIndex:[self.picker_timer selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
        NSString *minsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[minsArray objectAtIndex:[self.picker_timer selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
        NSString *secsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[secsArray objectAtIndex:[self.picker_timer selectedRowInComponent:2]]];

        int hoursInt = [hoursStr intValue];
        int minsInt = [minsStr intValue];
        int secsInt = [secsStr intValue];

        interval = secsInt + (minsInt*60) + (hoursInt*3600);
        secondsLeft=interval;
    }
    - (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
        if(secondsLeft > 0 )
        {
            secondsLeft -- ;
            hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
            minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
            seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:secondsLeft forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"secondsLeft_%@",recipeboxId]];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

            NSLog(@"timer :%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds]);
            NSString *timer_updated_value=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:timer_updated_value forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"updated_timer_%@",[(theAppDelegate).timer userInfo]]];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
             recipeArr = [[(theAppDelegate).Timer_recipeIdArr reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
            for (int section = 0; section < [recipeArr count]; section++)
                for (int section = 0; section < [recipeArr count]; section++)
                {

                    for (int row = 0; row < (int)[self.timerWindowTbl numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++)
                    {

                        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

                        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.timerWindowTbl cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                                for(UILabel *lbl in [cell.contentView subviews])
                                {
                                    if([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                                    {

                                        if(lbl.tag == 1)
                                        {
                                            NSString *timer_desc= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"timerDescString_%@",recipeArr[indexPath.row]]];
                                            NSString *recipe_title=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"timerRecipeTitle_%@",recipeArr[indexPath.row]]];
                                            NSString *updated_timer=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"updated_timer_%@",recipeArr[indexPath.row]]];

                                            NSString *desc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n'%@\' %@ %@.",recipe_title,timer_desc,NSLocalizedString(@"is done in",nil),updated_timer];
                                             lbl.text=updated_timer;
                                            [lbl setNeedsDisplay];

                                            NSLog(@"*******************************lbl.text:%@",lbl.text);
                                            lbl.numberOfLines=0;
                                            [lbl sizeToFit];
                                            for(UIButton *btn in [cell.contentView subviews])
                                            {
                                                if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                                                {
                                                    if(btn.tag==2)
                                                    {
                                                        btn.titleLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",recipeArr[indexPath.row]];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            break;

                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                         }
                }
        }
        else
        {
            secondsLeft = hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
            [self TimerInvalidate];
            NSLog(@"Time out :");
        }
    }
```

Comment: once you display the tableview, after that if you want to change the values inside tableview, you have to update the tableview. Else it will not display the new values.

Comment: it display new value but when i am from any recipe detail and come from next time its generate new object of tableview thats why any value not display.

Comment: when you coming from any recipe detail and come back, then don't create new object of tableview.

Comment: @Signare : please check this small demo https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw367uJS6w22MjBYeERQS0FSYm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: dont share your code publicly.

Comment: dnt wry this is my demo code. this code i share bcz u can understand easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104956/discussion-between-stela-and-signare).

Comment: @Stela try the demo project that i posted, hope this helps u

Comment: @Stela i edited the code u are shared check my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think u need to refractor your code, u need reload the tableview cell each time when recipe timer stared for particular recipe

this is sample demo u can try with separate project,
first create a `Recipe` class subclass of `NSObject` like below,

in `Recipe .h` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Recipe;
@protocol RecipeDelegate <NSObject> //we need to notify which recipe time changing
- (void)timerChangedInRecipe:(Recipe *)recipe;
@end


@interface Recipe : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger recipeboxId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *recipeName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *countTimer;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval secondsLeft;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval interval;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int hours;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int minutes;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int seconds;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<RecipeDelegate>delegate;

- (id)initWithRecipieId:(NSInteger)recipeId recipeName:(NSString *)name;
- (void )currentTimerString;
- (void)startTimer; //use to start the timer
- (void)stopTimer;  //stop the timer
```

@end

in `Recipe.m` file

```
#import "Recipe.h"

@implementation Recipe
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
  {

  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithRecipieId:(NSInteger)recipeId recipeName:(NSString *)name
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   {
      self.recipeboxId = recipeId;
      self.recipeName =  name;
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)currentTimerString //this is similar to your method updateCounter:
{
   self.secondsLeft -- ;
   if(self.secondsLeft > 0 )
   {
     _hours = (int)self.secondsLeft / 3600;
     _minutes = ((int)self.secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
     _seconds = ((int)self.secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
     self.countTimer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds];
      if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(timerChangedInRecipe:)]) 
         [self.delegate timerChangedInRecipe:self]; //notifying the tableview to reload the particular cell 
  }
  else
  {
     _hours = _minutes = _seconds = 0;
     [self stopTimer]; //timer finished stop the timer
  }
}

- (void)startTimer
 {
    if(_timer == nil)
      _timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.6f target:self selector:@selector(currentTimerString) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   else
       [_timer fire];
 }

 - (void)stopTimer
 {
    if(_timer)
      [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
 }
 @end
```

we are created the recipe object, this will handle the timer and notification to tableview, starting the timer and stoping the timer you can add some other functionalities if u want to.. :)

in `ViewController.h file`

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "Recipe.h" //import the recipe class
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,RecipeDelegate>
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *timerWindowTbl;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *recipeArr; //array to hold the recipes
 @end
```

in `ViewController.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   _recipeArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [self populateRecipe]; //i am simply creating the recipes hear for testing
 }

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }

 - (void)populateRecipe
 {
    for(NSInteger k = 0 ; k < 10 ; k++)
    {
      Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] initWithRecipieId:k recipe eName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"recipe_%ld",(long)k]];

     [self.recipeArr addObject:recipe];
   }
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 //just configure your tableview
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return 1;
 }


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    return self.recipeArr.count;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RECIPEE_CELL"];
   if(cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"RECIPEE_CELL"];
   }
   Recipe *recipe = self.recipeArr[indexPath.row];
   recipe.delegate = self;
   cell.textLabel.text = recipe.recipeName;
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = recipe.countTimer;
   return cell;
 }

 //hear go to recipe detail controller and set timer
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    Recipe *selRecipe = self.recipeArr[indexPath.row];
    RecipeDetailViewController *recipeDetailController = [[RecipeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
   recipeDetailController.selectedRecipe = selRecipe;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipeDetailController animated:YES];
 }

 //this is the delegate method from recipe class
 //this method is responsible for reloading the particular cell 
 - (void)timerChangedInRecipe:(Recipe *)recipe
 {
   NSInteger index = recipe.recipeboxId;
   NSIndexPath *rowPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
   [self.timerWindowTbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[rowPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
 } 
 @end
```

and in detail controller same as your recipe detail controller `RecipeDetailViewController.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Recipe.h"

@interface RecipeDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *timePicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *okButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Recipe *selectedRecipe;  
- (IBAction)okBtn:(id)sender;
@end
```

and in `RecipeDetailViewController .m` file,

```
 #import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"

 @interface RecipeDetailViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation RecipeDetailViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [_timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(timerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; //i am setting a sample picker
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (void)timerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePickerView
 {
    NSTimeInterval duration = datePickerView.countDownDuration;
    int hours = (int)(duration/3600.0f);
    int minutes = ((int)duration - (hours * 3600))/60;
    int seconds = minutes/60;
    _selectedRecipe.interval    = seconds + (minutes*60) + (hours*3600);
    _selectedRecipe.secondsLeft =_selectedRecipe.interval;
    _timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
   _selectedRecipe.interval = duration;
 }

 - (IBAction)okBtn:(id)sender //hear start the timer particular recipe
 {
   [_selectedRecipe startTimer];
 }
 @end
```

**Edit in the source code u are shared**
the problem in the cell type i think, if you want u can subclass the tableview cell and place the timer labels in the required position,

so in your code, `ViewController.m` file replace below method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RECIPEE_CELL"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"RECIPEE_CELL"];
    }
    Recipe *recipe = self.recipeArr[indexPath.row];
    recipe.delegate = self;
    cell.textLabel.text = recipe.recipeName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = recipe.countTimer;
    NSLog(@"timer in cell :%@",cell.detailTextLabel.text);
    return cell;
 }
```

and in the `RecipeDetailViewController.m` file replace,

```
 //no need to wait for value change 
- (IBAction)okBtn:(id)sender //hear start the timer particular recipe
 {
    NSTimeInterval duration = _timePicker.countDownDuration;
   _selectedRecipe.interval = duration;
   [_selectedRecipe startTimer];
 }
```

and also change the `timePicker` mode to `Count Down Timer` in attribute inspector

u can download the **edited** [code hear](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43nll8lsu9ncp6h/TimerDemo-2.zip?dl=0)

Comment: what happened ..? is there any problem .. ?

Comment: its working fine. TYSM @Shan
U deserved 100 likes :)

Comment: did u implemented the delegate method in the view controller that is having the tableview ..? and also check did u set the delegate while creating the recipe object

Comment: i don't get this,updated timer table is on the recipe detail controller ... ? u need to show detail of the selected recipe in recipe detail controller rite, and timer table is on the recipe list table

Comment: okay at a time only one timer value is displayed on detail screen for that particular recipe or timer for what user set for otters recipe also listed in the timer table

Answer (score 0):

Put UI related changes in main queue for better understanding show given below code. You can also put other UI related changes in Main_queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           lbl.text=updated_timer;

});
```